# Amqp.net - SSL authentication issue while running under Windows service

Tags: c#, amqp

I am using [AMQP.net](https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite) (amqpnetlite client) to communicate with IBM MQ.   Following code works fine when it is working as a standalone console application. 
But when same set of code is running under Windows Service, I am getting authentication failed error in creating connection line (`var connection = factory.CreateAsync(address1).Result`).

**Error:**

> InternalEndProcessAuthentication(System.Net.LazyAsyncResult)):
>   Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the
>   transport stream.

For SSL, I have created Self-signed certificate at server end and configured it in IBM MQ.  I have imported the certificate into Local computer Personal certificate storage.

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Amqp;
using Amqp.Framing;
using Amqp.Listener;
using Amqp.Sasl;



namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
            factory.SSL.ClientCertificates.Add(GetCertificate("SERVERMACHINENAME"));
            factory.SSL.Protocols = SslProtocols.TLS12 | SslProtocols.Ssl2;
            factory.SSL.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = ValidateServerCertificate;
            factory.SSL.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;

            var address1 = new Address(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ip"], Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["port"]), null, null, "/", "AMQPS");
            var connection = factory.CreateAsync(address1).Result;

            Session session = new Session(connection);

            Console.WriteLine("Creating ReceiverLink...");
            var _receiverLink = new ReceiverLink(session, "Test_Recv", "Test/Test");
            _receiverLink.Start(5, onMessage);

            Console.WriteLine("Creating SenderLink...");
            SenderLink sender = new SenderLink(session, "Test_Sender", "Test/Test");
            var message = new Message("Hello world");


            sender.Send(message);
            sender.Close();

            session.Close();
            _receiverLink.Close();
            connection.Close();

        }

        private static void  onMessage(ReceiverLink receiver, Message message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message Received");
            /// Parsing and sending to required system
        }


        static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            return true;
        }

        static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string certFindValue)
        {
            StoreLocation[] locations = new StoreLocation[] { StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreLocation.CurrentUser };
            foreach (StoreLocation location in locations)
            {
                X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, location);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

                X509Certificate2Collection collection = store.Certificates.Find(
                    X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
                    certFindValue,
                    false);

                if (collection.Count == 0)
                {
                    collection = store.Certificates.Find(
                        X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                        certFindValue,
                        false);
                }

                store.Close();

                if (collection.Count > 0)
                {
                    return collection[0];
                }
            }

            throw new ArgumentException("No certificate can be found using the find value " + certFindValue);
        }


    }
}
```

I tried without the following line and also with multiple combinations of sslprotocols. After searching SO, I arrived at the following line, but still same kind of error is coming.

```
factory.SSL.Protocols = SslProtocols.TLS12 | SslProtocols.Ssl2;
```

Is there any changes need to done while running as Windows service for SSL communication?

Comment: What is the user that is running your windows service? e.g. if you right click on it and go `Properties` - `Logon` what do you see there?

Comment: It's running under "manager". A custom made user name with administrator privileges.  As console application is working fine, I changed service to run under current logon user, but even then it fails.

Comment: I also struggle with IBM MQ, AMQP.Net, and SSL. The application breaks in the step where a new session is created based on the connection with the following exception message: _“The client and server cannot communicate because they do not process a common algorithm”_. Other combinations of SSL protocols as you specify just gives a more general exception: `{"amqp:connection:forced"}`.
To accomplish the goal of just successfully connect using SSL as you have managed, **can I ask you which SSL Cipher Spec your using on your IBM MQ AMQP channel?**

Comment: User265767: I am having the same issue. How did you solve it?

Comment: Have you tried to give the service user rights to Private Key in mmc.exe / add/remove snap in ... / certificates  [computer account]

Answer (score 0):

- Have you tried to give the service user rights to Private Key in mmc.exe / add/remove snap in ... / certificates [computer account]

[image]

[image]